# R using any() on multiple conditions within row

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like below;

```
library(dplyr);library(anytime)
set.seed(2450)
a <- c('V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V2','V2','V2','V3','V3','V3','V3','V4','V4','V4')
b <- c('Farm','Farm','Meat','Fish','Farm','Tag','Farm','Farm','Reg','Meat','Farm', 'Farm','Tag','Meat','Lifestyle','Reg')

c <-  sample(seq(anydate('2017-01-01'), anydate('2020-01-01'), by="day"), 16)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c) %>% group_by(a) %>% arrange(a, c) %>% mutate(Rank = row_number())
```

I am trying to identify any lines that meet various criteria which sometimes involves the group that they are within, I generally use case_when () to achieve this i.e. if I want to identify a Farm row where there are any other rows within that group that are 'Meat' i'd do:

```
df1 <- df %>% mutate(ID_col = case_when(b== 'Farm' & any(b) == 'Meat' ~ T)
```

But for one case I am trying to identify if any row with a earlier date than mine is b = "meat", so I added a rank column hoping to do a any() query where theres a row that has a higher rank than the row of interest and also has b == 'meat',

In cases where I don't care about row position I've previously:

```
library(stringr)
#pivot wider, unite, str_extract to get a list of words, then detect in that list using case_when 
wide <- df %>% 
        pivot_wider(id_cols = a, names_from = c values_from  = b) %>%
        unite(d, contains("-"), sep =",", na.rm=T) %>% 
        mutate(Extract = str_extract_all(d, "\\[a-z]+")) %>% 
        full_join(df) %>% 
        mutate(SY_Del = case_when(b == 'Farm' &
                                  str_detect(Extract, 'Meat') == T ~ T,
                              TRUE ~ F)
```

I'd thought about using an additional mutate whereby I extract anything in the list that's below the rank i.e. mutate(List_of_Interest = Extract[1][3:5]), although using the rank specifically in this subset

But I keep getting error messages, which I think is a symptom of me not extracting from the list correctly.

It would be great to get some ideas of how to achieve this as i think I'm overthinking it, and I'm sure there's an easier way.

In reality I just need to see if 'meat' is %in% a vector of column b below the row of interest within that group.

expected output is to flag any rows where there is a b=='meat' in any earlier (by date) row within that group.

```
     a         b          c Rank  Flag
1  V1      Farm 2017-01-08    1 FALSE
2  V1       Tag 2017-07-28    2 FALSE
3  V1      Fish 2017-11-13    3 FALSE
4  V1      Farm 2017-11-15    4 FALSE
5  V1      Meat 2018-03-27    5 FALSE
6  V1      Farm 2018-09-19    6 TRUE
7  V2      Farm 2017-07-20    1 FALSE
8  V2      Farm 2017-08-01    2 FALSE
9  V2       Reg 2018-09-27    3 FALSE
10 V3      Meat 2018-07-28    1 FALSE
11 V3      Farm 2018-09-28    2  TRUE
12 V3      Farm 2018-11-04    3  TRUE
13 V3       Tag 2018-12-16    4  TRUE
14 V4       Reg 2017-01-19    1 FALSE
15 V4 Lifestyle 2017-05-13    2 FALSE
16 V4      Meat 2017-12-31    3 FALSE
```

Comment: What is your expected output for given data?

Comment: Put it in, sorry, long day at work and missed that bit!

Comment: Are you sure about V2 grp expected output?  It's all `TRUE` in your post but there's no `Meat` in `b` for that group.

Comment: good eye! Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data frame ordered by group and date, you can use [`tidyr::fill()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html) to keep track of where `b == 'Meat'` in each group:

```
library(tidyr)

data.frame(a, b, c) %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  arrange(a, c) %>% 
  mutate(has_meat = if_else(b == "Meat", TRUE, NA)) %>%
  fill(has_meat, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(has_meat = if_else(b == "Meat", NA, has_meat)) %>%
  rename(meat_occurs_earlier = has_meat)

# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   a [4]
   a     b         c          meat_occurs_earlier
   <fct> <fct>     <date>     <lgl>              
 1 V1    Farm      2017-06-17 NA                 
 2 V1    Fish      2018-02-25 NA                 
 3 V1    Farm      2018-04-19 NA                 
 4 V1    Meat      2018-05-16 NA                 
 5 V1    Farm      2019-04-20 TRUE               
 6 V1    Tag       2019-08-10 TRUE               
 7 V2    Reg       2017-03-14 NA                 
 8 V2    Farm      2017-12-22 NA                 
 9 V2    Farm      2018-03-31 NA                 
10 V3    Meat      2017-01-15 NA                 
11 V3    Farm      2017-03-03 TRUE               
12 V3    Farm      2018-01-25 TRUE               
13 V3    Tag       2019-11-25 TRUE               
14 V4    Lifestyle 2017-03-18 NA                 
15 V4    Meat      2018-01-16 NA                 
16 V4    Reg       2018-10-27 TRUE
```

Steps:

1. Make a `has_meat` column which starts out simple: `TRUE` if `b == 'Meat'`, `NA` otherwise.
2. Since the data frame is ordered by group and date, you can use a downward `fill()` to make all the subsequent `has_meat` entries within each group `TRUE` as well.
3. Your problem statement says we should only flag rows in which `b == 'Meat'` *before* the row of interest, which means that the rows where `b =- 'Meat'` should not be flagged.  So we change the `has_meat == TRUE` rows to `NA` instead.
4. Rename `has_meat` - which isn't really an accurate column name anymore - to `meat_occurs_earlier`.

Note: Without example output, it's a little hard to be sure this is answering your question exactly.  The steps can be easily tweaked if, for example, you need to fill up instead of down.

Comment: Great! I can work with that, I hadn't thought to use fill in that way. Sorry about the lack of expected output, first question here!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.  And no worries re output, although you can always edit your post to make it clearer for others who come to learn from your question later on.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Also if this answers your question satisfactorily, please click the check mark next to the answer so that others know it's been resolved.