# R using any() on multiple conditions within row - More Complex Version

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, stringr

So the simpler version of this was solved here yesterday:
[R using any() on multiple conditions within row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63913744/r-using-any-on-multiple-conditions-within-row)

But, I'm not certain I can expand it to my second need whereby I am trying to identify if the ID in the From_ID is in any of the earlier To_ID rows within that group.

```
library(dplyr);library(anytime)


Tag <- c('V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V2','V2','V2','V3','V3','V3','V3','V4','V4','V4')
From_ID <- c('BL342','SD234','FR212','PX123','KJ214','BL342',  'FR231','BL231','CV231',   'KJ875','PX239','TR543','FR342',    'DS329','FR321','DF321')
To_ID <- c('FR212','BL342','SD234','FG342','BL342','KJ214',  'BL231','FR231','KJ123',   'FG432','KJ123','TR998','PX239',    'HG734','DF321','FR321')

Date <-  sample(seq(anydate('2017-01-01'), anydate('2020-01-01'), by="day"), 16)

df <- data.frame(Tag, From_ID, To_ID, Date) %>% group_by(Tag) %>% arrange(Tag, desc(Date)) %>% mutate(Rank = row_number())
```

In cases where I don't care about row position I've previously done:

```
library(stringr)
#pivot wider, unite, str_extract to get a list of words, then detect in that list using case_when 
wide <- df %>% 
        pivot_wider(id_cols = Tag, names_from = Date, values_from  = To_ID) %>%
        unite(d, contains("-"), sep =",", na.rm=T) %>% 
        mutate(Extract = str_extract_all(d, "\\[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}")) %>% 
        full_join(df) %>% 
        mutate(SY_Del = case_when(b == 'Farm' &
                                  str_detect(Extract, From_ID) == T ~ T,
                              TRUE ~ F)
```

expected output = Flag when the From_ID is included within any row with an earlier date than the one being evaluated i.e.
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m169M.png)

```
   Tag From_ID To_ID       Date Rank  Flag
1   V1   FR212 SD234 2019-08-24    1  TRUE
2   V1   BL342 KJ214 2019-05-05    2  TRUE
3   V1   PX123 FG342 2019-04-22    3 FALSE
4   V1   KJ214 BL342 2019-01-01    4 FALSE
5   V1   SD234 BL342 2018-09-13    5 FALSE
6   V1   BL342 FR212 2018-04-30    6 FALSE
7   V2   FR231 BL231 2019-09-16    1  TRUE
8   V2   CV231 KJ123 2018-01-07    2 FALSE
9   V2   BL231 FR231 2017-01-11    3 FALSE
10  V3   KJ875 FG432 2019-11-14    1 FALSE
11  V3   TR543 TR998 2019-10-26    2 FALSE
12  V3   FR342 PX239 2019-07-02    3 FALSE
13  V3   PX239 KJ123 2017-07-15    4 FALSE
14  V4   DS329 HG734 2019-01-30    1 FALSE
15  V4   DF321 FR321 2017-05-06    2  TRUE
16  V4   FR321 DF321 2017-03-20    3 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the 'Date' to `Date` class (`dmy` - from `lubridate`), `arrange` the data by 'Tag', 'Date', grouped by 'Tag', create the 'Flag2' column by looping over the `row_number`, check whether the element 'From_ID' is `%in%` the 'To_ID' from first row to that row, `ungroup` and `arrange` the dataset back in the original order based on 'Tag', 'Rank' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate) 
df %>%
     # // convert to Date class
     mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>% 
     # // order the dataset by Tag, Date
     arrange(Tag, Date) %>% 
     # // grouped by Tag
     group_by(Tag) %>% 
     # // loop over the sequence of rows
     mutate(Flag2 = map_lgl(row_number(),
           # // check whether the 'From_ID' of that row is in 
           # // any of the previous row elements of 'To_ID'
           ~ From_ID[.x] %in% To_ID[1:(.x)])) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     # // order back to original
     arrange(Tag, Rank)
# A tibble: 16 x 7
#   Tag   From_ID To_ID Date        Rank Flag  Flag2
#   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <date>     <int> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 V1    FR212   SD234 2019-08-24     1 TRUE  TRUE 
# 2 V1    BL342   KJ214 2019-05-05     2 TRUE  TRUE 
# 3 V1    PX123   FG342 2019-04-22     3 FALSE FALSE
# 4 V1    KJ214   BL342 2019-01-01     4 FALSE FALSE
# 5 V1    SD234   BL342 2018-09-13     5 FALSE FALSE
# 6 V1    BL342   FR212 2018-04-30     6 FALSE FALSE
# 7 V2    FR231   BL231 2019-09-16     1 TRUE  TRUE 
# 8 V2    CV231   KJ123 2018-01-07     2 FALSE FALSE
# 9 V2    BL231   FR231 2017-01-11     3 FALSE FALSE
#10 V3    KJ875   FG432 2019-11-14     1 FALSE FALSE
#11 V3    TR543   TR998 2019-10-26     2 FALSE FALSE
#12 V3    FR342   PX239 2019-07-02     3 FALSE FALSE
#13 V3    PX239   KJ123 2017-07-15     4 FALSE FALSE
#14 V4    DS329   HG734 2019-01-30     1 FALSE FALSE
#15 V4    DF321   FR321 2017-05-06     2 TRUE  TRUE 
#16 V4    FR321   DF321 2017-03-20     3 FALSE FALSE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Tag = c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V2", 
"V2", "V2", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V4", "V4", "V4"), From_ID = c("FR212", 
"BL342", "PX123", "KJ214", "SD234", "BL342", "FR231", "CV231", 
"BL231", "KJ875", "TR543", "FR342", "PX239", "DS329", "DF321", 
"FR321"), To_ID = c("SD234", "KJ214", "FG342", "BL342", "BL342", 
"FR212", "BL231", "KJ123", "FR231", "FG432", "TR998", "PX239", 
"KJ123", "HG734", "FR321", "DF321"), Date = c("24/08/2019", "5/05/2019", 
"22/04/2019", "1/01/2019", "13/09/2018", "30/04/2018", "16/09/2019", 
"7/01/2018", "11/01/2017", "14/11/2019", "26/10/2019", "2/07/2019", 
"15/07/2017", "30/01/2019", "6/05/2017", "20/03/2017"), Rank = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
    Flag = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```

Comment: Could you explain this code for me, I understand the premise but not sure I could have built it myself. mutate(Flag2 = map_lgl(row_number(),
           ~ From_ID[.x] %in% To_ID[1:(.x)])) %>%

Comment: Also I changed the expected output date, excel had changed it on me when I was manually creating output. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Medwards it's okay.  I changed it with `dmy`.  thanks

Comment: So just to see if I'm following if I wanted to skip the steps where you flip the direction back and forth, could I define the %in% To_ID [(.x): max(Rank) ] ?

Comment: @Medwards If you are not flipping, if the `Rank` is based on already ordered 'Date', then you don't need to `arrange` again, just use the same code with `row_number()` or `Rank` i.e. `map(Rank, ~`